# How to calculate the p-value of a test, that checked for a binary property?

Tags: python, p-value, contingency-tables, scipy, control-group

16081 subjects were randomly assigned into two groups:

- test group: 7916 subjects
- control group: 8165 subjects

Only the test group was exposed to something. During the test period

- 10 subjects of the test group
- 8 subjects of the control group

showed a specific behavior (only true or false possible).

How can I calculate the p-value for this result, i.e., the probability of the exposition not having any effect on the occurrence of this behavior?

---

My current attempt (in Python 3) looks as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

test_group_size = 7916
test_group_true = 10
test_group_false = test_group_size - test_group_true

control_group_size = 8165
control_group_true = 8
control_group_false = control_group_size - control_group_true

expected_true = control_group_true * test_group_size / control_group_size
expected_false = control_group_false * test_group_size / control_group_size

_, p_value = chisquare([test_group_true, test_group_false],
                       f_exp=[expected_true, expected_false])

print(p_value)
```

The output is

```
0.4201628893079947
```

But is this correct?

---

It differs quite a lot from the `0.296`, that these two websites output:

- [abtestguide](https://abtestguide.com/calc/) -> [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN1pg.png)
- [vwo](https://vwo.com/ab-split-test-significance-calculator/) -> [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MVg9.png)

Abtestguide allows to choose between one-sided and two-sided, but the p-value does not change with this choice:

- [one-sided](https://abtestguide.com/calc/?ua=8165&ub=7916&ca=8&cb=10)
- [two-sided](https://abtestguide.com/calc/?ua=8165&ub=7916&ca=8&cb=10&tail=2)

Might this be a bug in the code of the website?

---

From looking at the source code of one of them, I re-created the result in python:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

test_group_size = 7916
test_group_true = 10

control_group_size = 8165
control_group_true = 8

true_rate_a = control_group_true / control_group_size
true_rate_b = test_group_true / test_group_size

se_a_sq = (true_rate_a * (1 - true_rate_a)) / control_group_size
se_b_sq = (true_rate_b * (1 - true_rate_b)) / test_group_size

se_diff = np.sqrt(se_a_sq + se_b_sq)
zScore = (true_rate_b - true_rate_a) / se_diff

p_value = 1 - norm.cdf(zScore, 0, 1)
print(p_value)
```

output:

```
0.2958346408590914
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange the results as a $2\times 2$-table and use `chi2_contigency` from SciPy in Python to obtain the correct $p$-value (here shown without continuity correction):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency, fisher_exact

obs = np.array([[8157, 8],[7906,10]])

g, p, dof, expctd = chi2_contingency(obs, correction = False)

p

0.59094761107842753
```

So the $p$-value is roughly $0.5909$.

A viable alternative would be to use Fisher's exact test. This can be done using `fisher_exact` from SciPy:

```
oddsr, p_fish = fisher_exact(obs)

oddsr

1.289685049329623

p_fish

0.64294290970149048
```

The odds ratio is $1.29$ with an associated $p$-value from Fisher's exact test of $0.643$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I just found these two websites: [abtestguide](https://abtestguide.com/calc/) and [vwo](https://vwo.com/ab-split-test-significance-calculator/), which should basically do the same. However they both output `0.296` with my values ([result from abtestguide](https://i.imgur.com/yoHlnD9.png), result from [vwo](https://i.imgur.com/x6Vsw75.png)). Any idea on why these values are so much different from yours?
(I'll add these links to my question too.)

Comment: @TobiasHermann The results are different because these websites apply a one-sided test. Note that the $p$-value of $0.295$ is exactly half of mine $0.59$.

Comment: Mhh, but the p-value on this website does not change, no matter if I choose [one-sided](https://abtestguide.com/calc/?ua=8165&ub=7916&ca=8&cb=10) or [two-sided](https://abtestguide.com/calc/?ua=8165&ub=7916&ca=8&cb=10&tail=2). Is this a bug in their code?

Comment: @TobiasHermann Probably, I don't know. But the $p$-value from Python is definitely correct (for a two-sided test).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here seems to be a confusion over one and two sided tests. The value of 0.64 is for a two-sided test (confirmed using R) but the websites are doing one-sided tests although I get 0.38 for that which I suspect is due to a difference in how the web-sites treat the $p$-value for the obtained table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could treat this as a 2x2 contingency table and use [Fisher's Exact Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

So, I'd recommend you use `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` instead of chisquare.

Comment: COOLSerdash beat me to it. :-)